# Ckeditor: Using Firefox built in spellchecker

Tags: ckeditor, spell-checking

I feel a little caught between a rock and a hard place here. I want to use Firefox's built in spell checking without disabling Ckeditor's context menu as this renders it impossible to work with tables. Is there a way of getting the best of both worlds here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try setting the [disableNativeSpellChecker](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.disableNativeSpellChecker) property to false - it *should* then be possible to see the native spell checker markings within the editor - however for me I couldn't get this to work in Firefox, only Google chrome.

You can then hold the ctrl key down when you right click to show the browser context menu (provided browserContextMenuOnCtrl has not been set to false)

HTH.

Comment: I tried something like that (I think it was that option) and I was able to see the red underlines, but not right click them.

Comment: Certainly in Chrome on windows, I can right click on the red underlines provided I hold down the windows key - and the browser context menu pops up, together with the spell check suggestions etc...

Check that browserContextMenuOnCtrl is not set to false if that isn't working for you  (it defaults to true)

Comment: @Kimble, you can't see them with right-click unless you hold down the "ctrl" button.

Answer (score 8):

Use the browser's default contextmenu for right click action, then you don't need to press *Ctrl* to shoe the browser's default context menu.

```
config.removePlugins = 'scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';
```

Enable the built-in spell checker if the browser provides one.

```
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

hi there you can disable it by going to

Ckeditor>File Editor.then make sure you're editing the **ckeditor.config.js** file!

then add the two lines at the bottom (after the **};** tag) add the two lines like below!...

****> CKEDITOR.config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;

> CKEDITOR.config.browserContextMenuOnCtrl = true;****

then save it..........
when writing in ckeditor a red dot underline will appear if your spell is incorrect!
when you right click the ckeditor's context menu appear.....but when you Ctrl+Right Click the browsers default menu appears....thanks..........

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin: http://martinezdelizarrondo.com/spellcheck/ and as it's stated, you have to install the WriteArea extension in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, it's a shame if this isn't possible without installing a browser plugin though.

Comment: Firefox doesn't expose any way to access its spellchecker from a web page script, so the extension includes that option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable SCAYT (SpellCheckAsYouType) in CKeditor? It is buit-in there and works as a plug-in.

Comment: I had a brief look at it, but it costs money and I'm a little reluctant to pay for something that's already built into modern browsers.