# Where can I find "ckeditor.config.js"?

Tags: ckeditor, spell-checking, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 and I am trying to set `config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false` as shown at the answers of the following question:
[Ckeditor: Using Firefox built in spellchecker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682042/ckeditor-using-firefox-built-in-spellchecker)

I am new to Drupal and everybody is referring to `ckeditor.config.js`
I couldn't find any information on where to find this file.

I tried all subfolders of `/core/modules/ckeditor` but couldn't find it.

Is it not there by default and I have to create it?

Where?

One of the answers for the question in the link above is referring to ckeditor > file editor to edit the file. What is that and how to find it?

Answer (score 1):

did you try checking http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Open_Source/Drupal_7/Configuration

according to the documentation

> You can also adjust CKEditor to your needs by changing the `sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js` configuration file.
>
> It is recommended to **not edit** the config.js (sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/config.js) configuration file that is distributed with CKEditor, because you may overwrite it accidentally when you update the editor.

So everything should be done through the administrative panel of the `CKEditor` module inside Drupal.

the documentation is for Drupal 7, but Drupal 8 shouldn't differ much, I hope it helps!

**UPDATE**
After some research, apparently there is no way in Drupal 8 to edit the `ckeditor` global configuration out of the box.

There is issue and patch will be in `Drupal v8.1.x` check https://www.drupal.org/node/2307141

All you can do is install a spell check plugin for `CKEditor`

But if you want to go all nuts, you need to override the settings via a hook or a plugin.